# Android app "Device or resource busy" when accessing USB device via JNA

Tags: java, android, jna

In making use of JNA in an Android app, I encounter a `LastErrorException` with the message `Device or resource busy` when I attempt to perform an ioctl operation on a USB device. I cannot guess why this is or what to do about it. Can anyone offer any guidance at all?

I am in fact using a 3rd-party snippet, whose source is viewable [here](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/UsbIso/UsbIso.java).

The error I get reads as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-556
  Process: edu.ucdavis.auditoryenhancer, PID: 31335
  com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [16] Device or resource busy
      at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
      at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:390)
      at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
      at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
      at biz.source_code.usb.$Proxy0.ioctl(Unknown Source)
      at biz.source_code.usb.UsbIso.setInterface(UsbIso.java:414)
```

My own code that leads up to this error stack is as follows:

```
// the variable "dev" is an instance of android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice
UsbInterface interface = dev.getInterface(2);
UsbEndpoint endpoint = dev.getEndpoint(0);
UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbMgr.openDevice(dev);
new UsbIso(connection.getFileDescriptor(), 1, endpoint.getMaxPacketSize());
try {
    usbIso.setInterface(getInterfaceNumber(), getAlternateSetting());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you use the "lsof" shell command to see whether another process has opened the device?

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse : Thanks for asking. I've run `lsof | grep dev` (my device name is currently `/dev/bus/usb/003/005`), but no match comes up.

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse : I've just experimented with removing the line that calls `usbIso.setInterface`, and I no longer get the "Device or resource busy" error. (I do get a different error, however, after ~1300 packets are read.) Do I need to call `setInterface` if I have specified an interface and an endpoint in my `UsbDeviceConnection`, do you think?

Comment: setInterface(n) should start streaming mode and setInterface(0) should stop it. I guess that your device is already in streaming mode and is in use by some driver.

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't call UsbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(). I call it for the control interface and for the streaming interface of an UVC camera device.

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse : Thanks for pointing that out. I believe that proves to be the resolution to my problem.

Comment: For future reference (to myself, it no one else), the `UsbIso.setInterface` function appears to require values that correspond to `lsusb` output and not to the indices that the `UsbManager.getInterface` function requires. Ergo, I would recommend `usbIso.setInterface(intf.getId(), LSUSB_VALUE)`