# USBFS IOCTL call witn JNA doesn't work in 64 bits architectures

Tags: java, android, usb, jna

In Android, I'm using a class ([UsbIso.java](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/UsbIso/UsbIso.java)) to transfer data in an isochronous way from a USB device attached. Since Android doesn't natively support isochronous transfers, I had to use the USBFS native Linux mechanism through the JNA library to make the proper ioctl calls.

In Android devices with 32-bit architecture (armeabi, armeabi-v7a) everything works properly. In Android devices with 64-bit architecture (arm64-v8a) the ioctl call to reap URB (USBDEVFS_REAPURB, inside the reapRequest method, see related code below) returns error 14, bad address. I guess that this is caused either by the USBDEVFS_REAPURB parameter or by the PointerByReference parameter, which points to a non-valid virtual address, but I have no clue about how to solve it.

The related code in the UsbIso.java class that causes this error is this:

```
public Request reapRequest (boolean wait) throws IOException {
        PointerByReference urbPointer = new PointerByReference();
        int func = wait ? USBDEVFS_REAPURB : USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY;
        int rc;
        try {
            rc = libc.ioctl(fileDescriptor, func, urbPointer);  // <-- Error 14, bad address
        } catch (LastErrorException e) {
            if (e.getErrorCode() == EAGAIN && !wait) {
                return null; 
            }
        }
...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using source code optimized for 32-bit:

```
// Note: The layout and size of the USBFS structures matches that of Linux Kernel 3.2 and 3.14
// for ARM 32 bit. For other environments (X86, 64 bit, future Linux kernels), it might be
// necessary to adjust some values.
```

While JNA would normally adjust a structure mapping for 32- vs. 64- bit, this code thinks JNA is too slow and manually maps those offsets:

```
// This class is modeled after struct usbdevfs_urb in <linuxKernel>/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h
// At first I implemented the URB structure directly using com.sun.jna.Structure, but that was extremely slow.
// Therefore byte offsets are now used to access the fields of the structure.
```

If you look at the [structure mapping for `usbdevfs_urb`](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/6eb782fc88d11b9f40f3d1d714531f22c57b39f9/include/linux/usbdevice_fs.h#L96) there are 3 pointer fields that need adjusting from a 4-byte offset to an 8-byte offset.  For example, the 5th field `buffer` changes from 4 bytes to 8 bytes, so this code breaks:

```
   public void setBuffer (Pointer buffer) {
      urbBuf.putInt(12, (int)Pointer.nativeValue(buffer)); }
   public void setBufferLength (int bufferLength) {
      urbBuf.putInt(16, bufferLength); }
```

In particular, the `putInt(12, (int) ...)` should probably be `putLong(12, ...)` and the 16 in the next call should be 20 (and so on adding 4 to the remaining offsets.)

The last two fields are also 8 byte vs. 4 byte, so the `setUserContext()` and `getUserContext()` need to deal with `long` rather than `int` and the `urbBaseSize` needs incrementing from 44 to 52 (+4 for the `buffer`, +4 for the `userContext`.

I see a few other `int` variables representing memory addresses that would need to become `long`s.  There may be other changes required that I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the last answer of this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888801/android-usb-isochronous-data-transfer/) by Peter Stoiber, there exists a class which solves this problem: https://github.com/Peter-St/Android-UVC-Camera/tree/master/app/src/main/java/humer/uvc_camera/UsbIso64